# Ruby variable seems to be nil but is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the error `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` at the marked line. The logger shows that `hash` in not nil. It seems I don't call this method on anyhing else in that line. What am I missing here?

```
def initialize(hash)
    Rails.logger.debug "Attr init hash: #{hash.inspect}, nil?: #{hash.nil?}"
    self.name = hash[:name] #error here
    self.type = hash[:type]
    self.default_value = hash[:default_value]
    self.original_name = if hash[:original_name]
                           hash[:original_name]
                         else
                           name
                         end
  end
```

This is the output of the logger:

```
Attr init asdasd: {:name=>"join_id.alma", :type=>"", :default_value=>"", :original_name=>nil}, nil?: false
```

Comment: Could you show the value of the `hash`?

Comment: I added the line outputted by the logger.

Comment: Can you print the hash class.name just for be sure that this is an hash and not anything else with the same, or similiar format?

Comment: Logger output does not match exactly what the code should produce. Where does `asdasd:` come from in the output? Is this the same code that is causing the error?

Comment: Can you show the `name=` method? Maybe the whole class where the `initialize` is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You overrode `initialize` and therefore your `ActiveRecord` object wasn't initialized correctly. The error is raised because `self.name` internally tried to update the instance's `attributes` hash and fails.

When you override the `initialize` method it makes sense to call `super` to run the default `initialize` method first:

```
def initialize(hash)
  super(hash.slice(:name, :type, :default_value))
  self.original_name = hash[original_name] || name
end
```

Comment: This is almost right. I used Mongoid as the object-mapper, but the same thing applies.